# ANSYS APDL Shape memory effect option of SMA not working

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, ansys, alloys

I am trying to define the material properties of a shape memory alloy material in ANSYS APDL V15. There are material properties for Superelastic materials (SUPE option) and material properties for Shape memory effect materials (MEFF option) depending on the option taken. Even after taking the right option for shape memory effect, the data shown is not the right model.

My code for defining the material with the trigger is as follows:

```
/PREP7  
MP,EX,2,47.2E9
MP,PRXY,2,0.33
TB,SMA,2,1,7,MEFF,,  
TBDATA,1,0,315.15,100E6,4.4E6,0.05,2.0E10  
TBDATA,7,0
```

The output windows confirms that I took the memory effect option by saying:

```
DEFINE DATA TABLE  SMA   FOR MATERIAL     2  
Shape Memory Alloys OPTION  MEMORY EFFECT  
WITH A MAXIMUM OF  1 TEMPERATURES AND    7 DATA POINTS
```

However, the material model still displays the material constants as being "SIG-SAS, SIG-FAS, SIG-SSA, SIG-FSA, EPSILON, ALPHA" for a total of 6 constants. These correspond to the SUPE option.

Both the name and number of constants correspond to the Superelastic model and not the Shape memory effect, which I should have triggered using the MEFF option.

Why is this happening? How do I define this material using the constants for the Shape memory effect, rather than the constants for the Superelastic model?

Comment: This question seems more suitable specifically to an ANSYS mailing list or forum.

Comment: I am also trying to do FE analysis of SMA in ANSYS. You have to add YMRT (Martensite young's modulus) as well. Try again with that option.

Comment: @Paul Ansys does not have a very good active user community elsewhere. while there is a tag on this website for ANSYS , why are you redirecting the users ?

Comment: Isn't is just a problem of showing wrong parameter set in GUI? ANSYS MAPDL has some functions available only through APDL. You could do a simple analysis, from which differences between superelastic a shape memory materials would be apparent, to check which model is really used.